# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{(n^{2} +n)^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Evaluate  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{(n^{2}+n)^{2}}.$$

I am getting two different results by using two different methods -

**First Method**

The above sum can be written as

\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{N} (1/n^{2}  - 1/(n+1)^{2})&= 1 - 1/4 + 1/4 - 1/9 \dots -1/(N+1)^{2}\\ &= 1 - 1/(N+1)^{2} \end{align}

Taking the limit as $N\to\infty$, we have the the sum equal to $1$.

**Second Method**

Above sum is equal to -
\begin{align}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2x+1}{(x^{2}+x)^{2}}\,dx\end{align}

Put $x^2 + x = t$

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} dt/t^{2}$$

$=[-1/t]_{2}^{\infty}$

$=1/2$

Why are these methods are giving different results?

Comment: The sum and the integral are **not** equal. That is why you're getting different answers.

Comment: For n=1, the first term would be $3/4$. You missed something in your second method.

Comment: @Clayton By cauchy integral test, this sum and the integral (in second method) should behave alike. So, why there values are different?

Comment: They behave similarly, but that doesn't imply they represent the same numbers.

Comment: A visual argument might help to see why the two are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Integral Test for series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) does ***NOT*** assert that the infinite series and the improper integral are equal to each other. In fact, from the proof, it can be seen that they can't possibly be equal to each other (except for maybe some carefully constructed step functions, if we relax the continuity requirement). The test only says that if the integral converges, then the series converges as well (and the same for divergence), but it does not provide a value for the series in this case (although it does provide a useful remainder estimate). In short:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)\color{red}{\neq}\int_1^{\infty}f(x)\,dx,$$
which is why your second "method" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In context, hopefully not too trivial.

Let $f(n)=\dfrac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^2}$, $f(n)$ is strictly decreasing.

1)Your sum $\sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)$ is an upper sum

for the integral  $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

$U :=\sum_{1}^{\infty}f(n)=1$;

2)Now consider the lower sum:

$\sum_{2}^{\infty}f(n)$ for the integral.

$L := \sum_{2}^{\infty}f(n)=1/4;$

We have

$L =1/4 < 1/2$ (Integral)$ < U=1$.

See:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Link given by Zipirovic.